# Adding views to different el based on condition in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've got a problem with my Backbone.js app (**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/bew7x010/3/). The app is list (ol element) with nested lists within. Here's my starting HTML:

```
<body>
    <ol id="flowList"></ol>
</body>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <%= content %>
</script>
```

When the list is empty. I add a new `<li>` element within it using Backbone.js and focus on the `li`.

When within the `li`, if I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, I want to insert a new `li` just after the `li` I pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> within.

If I press <kbd>tab</kbd>, I want to add a new sub `ol` element within the list element. I handle the keypress within the `li` elements like so:

```
handleKeyboardShortcuts: function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.el = $(e.target).parent();
        Items.create({contnet: "New Item!"});
    }
}
```

I have a `listenTo` on my collection, which on add, appends a `li` to the `#flowList ol` element using the `addOne` function:

```
addOne: function(todo) {
    var view = new ItemView({model: todo});
    $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
}
```

My problem is:

1. How do I pass the target element to add to, to the `addOne` function?
2. How do I pass an option to the `addOne` function, which instead of doing `$(this.el).append` does `$(this.el).after` ?

For some reason, I can't get my head around how to pass around those details. Here's the full Backbone.js code:

```
$(function() {
    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {
      return {
        content: "empty item..."
      };
    }

    });

    var ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item,
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-backbone"),
    });

    var Items = new ItemList;

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:  "li",

        template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

        events: {
          "click": "enableEdit",
          "blur": "disableEdit",
        },

        initialize: function() {
          this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
          this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
        },

        render: function() {
          this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
          return this;
        },

        enableEdit: function(){
            this.$el.attr("contenteditable","true").focus();
        },

        disableEdit: function(){
            this.$el.attr("contenteditable","false");
        }
    });

   var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#flowList"),

    events: {
      "keydown li": "handleKeyboardShortcuts"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(Items, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(Items, 'reset', this.addAll);
        this.listenTo(Items, 'all', this.render);

        Items.fetch();

        if (Items.length === 0){
            Items.create({content: "Sample Item!"});
        }
    },

    render: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    },

    addOne: function(todo) {
      var view = new ItemView({model: todo});
      $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
    },

    addAll: function() {
      Items.each(this.addOne, this);
    },

    handleKeyboardShortcuts: function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.el = $(e.target).parent();
            Items.create({contnet: "New Item!"});
        }
    }
  });

  var App = new AppView;
});
```

Here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/bew7x010/3/

Comment: for your question "How do I pass an option to the addOne function, which instead of doing $(this.el).append does $(this.el).after ?"
When you do this.el = $(e.target).parent(); you are making this.el to point to parent and when you do$(this.el).append(view.render().el); you are "appending" to parent which is same as "after" to this.el

Also its better to do this
var src = e.src || e.originalTarget || e.target;
 this.el = $(src).parent();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the selected item, enabling you to insert the new one after or within it.

In your existing enableEdit handler, trigger an 'item:select' event:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    enableEdit: function(){
        this.trigger('item:select', this);
        this.$el.attr("contenteditable","true").focus();
    }
});
```

Then in your AppView, when you add a new item, attach a listener for the new item that updates the value of a 'selectedItem' property.

Then you can insert the new item into the dom based on the state of that property:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    addOne: function(todo) {
        var view = new ItemView({model: todo});
        this.listenTo( view, 'item:select', this.handleItemSelect );

        if(this.selectedItem) {
            $(this.selectedItem.el).after(view.render().el);
        }
        else {
            $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
        }
    },
    handleItemSelect: function(item) {
       console.log('item selected:', item);
       this.selectedItem = item;
   }
});
```

You should be able to do something similar for the tab key behaviour, by setting a flag when the tab key is pressed, before calling Items.create.

Comment: Anybody care to explain the downvote? Is this not the best way to do it?